# WPF-Program crashs on database access after upgrade to Windows10, but only in 64bit-Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, 32bit-64bit, windows-10

i wrote a program (**WPF, .NET4.6, C#6, EF6.1.3, MSSQLExpress**) which used to run fine, then i upgraded from Windows7 64bit to Windows10 64bit, now it crashs.

Debugging-Time: As soon as it tries to get some data from the DB it crashs. 
Visual Studio 2015 -> Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe does not respond and also vshost.exe

If i set the **Plattformtarget** within my projects **to x84** (instead of Any CPU), my program runs fine.

There is a similar PC upgraded from Windows8.1 64bit to Windows10 64bit, the program runs fine no matter what Plattformtarget.

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First-Approach, the error happens when i try to get data from a DbSet in my DbContext.

Something like

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
  var dc = new DataContext();

  var persons = dc.Persons.ToList(); // CRASH
}
```

The database i'm using is the built-in SQLEXPRESS from Windows.

Has anyone any clou whats the problem?

Comment: What is the exception type?

Comment: Reading your question is a lock and not a crash. A timeout connecting to SQL? Something related to the connection string (I don't think so but have a look to the 2 PCs)? Or with some service pack? You could also change the connection protocol and use TCP/IP (in SQL Express is disabled by default).

Comment: @GlenThomas there is no exception, if i start my code in visualstudio everything works until the code reaches the point with db access and than i got two Windows-Messages Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe and vshost.exe are not responding

Comment: @bubi But why does it work if i compile it to x86?

Comment: Also, why on another PC works fine? Service Pack, different SQL configuration (Shared memory connection instead of TCP/IP). You could also run the SQL Server profiler to understand where the process hangs (Connection/Select ... from __MigrationHistory/...) or, if you use TCP/IP Wireshark or another sniffer. BTW I don't have this problem on first tests (3 clients over some hundreds of Win 7/8/8.1).

Comment: @bubi thank you for the many tips, i'll start with SQL Server Profiler